# How do I draw this cyclic graph in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

[image]

Hey all, using Geogebra then exporting the above into my latex file I can get these two graphs but I have no idea how to possibly go about drawing this in latex "simply" as the code looks really messy...I was up all night yesterday but I didn't get anywhere...Is there a kind soul out there who can maybe do one and I will attempt the other?

Many thanks,

Gentle

PS: Is it possible to label maybe one or two of the vertices and not the others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question can be solved with the node shape of a regular polygon:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[
    regular polygon,
    regular polygon sides=16,
    minimum size=4cm,
    rotate=180/16,
  ] (a) {};
  \draw[blue]
    (a.corner 15) \foreach \i in {16, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5} { -- (a.corner \i) }
    (a.corner 7) \foreach \i in {8, ..., 14} { -- (a.corner \i) }
  ;
  \draw[densely dashed]
    (a.corner 5) -- (a.corner 14)
    (a.corner 7) -- (a.corner 15)
  ;
  \fill[radius=1pt] \foreach \i in {1, ..., 16} { (a.corner \i) circle[] };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The second one is similar:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[
    regular polygon,
    regular polygon sides=16,
    minimum size=4cm,
    rotate=180/16,
  ] (a) {};
  \draw[blue]
    (a.corner 14) \foreach \i in {15, 16, 1, 2, 3} { -- (a.corner \i) }
    (a.corner 5) \foreach \i in {6, ..., 13} { -- (a.corner \i) }
  ;
  \draw[densely dashed]
    (a.corner 3) -- (a.corner 13)
    (a.corner 5) -- (a.corner 14)
  ;
  \fill[radius=1pt] \foreach \i in {1, ..., 16} { (a.corner \i) circle[] };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### Alternative approach with polar coordinates without node

In the following example the corners are numbered from 0 to 15, counterclockwise, starting at angle zero in the right.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path
    (0, 0)
    \foreach \i in {0, ..., 15} {
      +(360/16 * \i:3cm) coordinate (corner \i)
    }
  ;
  \draw[blue]
    (corner 2) \foreach \i in {3, ..., 8} { -- (corner \i) }
    (corner 10) \foreach \i in {11, ..., 15, 0, 1} { -- (corner \i) }
  ;
  \draw[densely dashed]
    (corner 1) -- (corner 8)
    (corner 2) -- (corner 10)
  ;
  \fill[radius=1pt] \foreach \i in {0, ..., 15} { (corner \i) circle[] };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with polar coordinates]